# How to reslove: "JVM exited while loading the application" in order to run a Mule application in Anypoint studio

Tags: jvm, wrapper, mule-studio

I am new to use Mulesoft and thus I have started learning it by following the steps in "https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/build-a-hello-world-application".

However, when I try to run the project by selecting "Run As > Mule Application", It gives me this error messages:

Launching a JVM...
JVM exited while loading the application.
Automatic JVM Restarts disabled.  Shutting down.
backend pipe closed.
backend pipe closed.
<-- Wrapper Stopped

Note that: I am using Windows 7 (64 bit), Mulesoft 7.1 (64 bit), jdk1.8.0_171 (64 bit) and I have added java home into system variable as instructed in this post "https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/90429/unable-to-install-mule-4-anypoint-studio-71.html"

Any suggestion, please !!!

Comment: Note that the hello world that you are trying to run is for Mule 3, thus incompatible with Mule 4/Studio 7. From the error it looks you are using the later versions. This is not the cause of your issue, however it will never execute.

Answer (score 0):

See image and check your Run configuration I have post image under bellow url...

[image]